# Python 3.6. blocking I/O. Server doesn't accept any request while first request in process

Tags: async-await, python-3.5, python-asyncio, aiohttp

The problem is that the server doesn't accept any request until the first request given hasn't returned.

```
import asyncio
import datetime as dt
from aiohttp import web


async def search(request):
    print('!START! %s' % dt.datetime.now())

    await asyncio.sleep(5)

    print('!--END! %s' % dt.datetime.now())
    return web.json_response(data={})


app = web.Application()
app.router.add_get('/search/', search)

web.run_app(app)


#run_server
#python -m aiohttp.web -H localhost -P 8080 handler:init_func
```

Example:
I've run http://localhost:8080/search/ in two tabs almost at the same time.
But I've seen requests are being processed sequentially.

```
!START! 2017-04-24 12:05:37.978347
!--END! 2017-04-24 12:05:47.980859
!START! 2017-04-24 12:05:48.037671
!--END! 2017-04-24 12:05:58.040659
```

But I expected requests will be processed parallel.

```
!START! 2017-04-24 12:05:37.978347
!START! 2017-04-24 12:05:38.000000
!--END! 2017-04-24 12:05:47.980859
!--END! 2017-04-24 12:05:48.000000
```

What have I done anything wrong?

Comment: how are you calling the `search(request)` function? please provide a [minimal, complete and verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: for @hiroprotagonist

`from views import search

app = web.Application()
app.router.add_get('/search/', search)
routes.setup(app)`

Comment: Can you explain more about your's problem? What do you mean by "until the first request given hasn't returned"?

Comment: Cannot reproduce. Your example is working as expected (couple time running `curl http://localhost:8080/search/ &`).

Comment: Really, it is working with curl as parallel. Thank you! 
But I've run in the FireFox and I've got sequentially. Why does browser work as sequentially? @kwarunek

Comment: Probably some kind of "throttling", I am aware of some limit of concurrent requests per domain but I thought it is higher (tens of requests). Maybe inactive tab has lower priority...

Comment: Thank you! I've tried 2 requests with different GET params and got necessary result.
http://localhost:8080/search/?a=1
http://localhost:8080/search/?a=2
@kwarunek

Answer (score 1):

Most browsers internally use connection pool and don't create new connection to the same host. Thus two pages shares the same opened socket.